# Truth table of a LM393 comparotor

Tags: comparison

Need a truth table of the part http://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product_10001_10001_24281_-1
Have looked every where but never found one. 
Please find one it will save me a lot of time and money.(as well as make the thing ime building faster.

Sorry if I posted it in wrong thread :(

Edit: it should be in mathematics because truth tables are part of Boolean algebra.

Comment: You might find http://home.cogeco.ca/~rpaisley4/Comparators.html helpful

Comment: In the future, please ask questions about electronics on [electronics.SE] – however this one might be considered too specific to one certain part.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a truth table for an analog function. This is a standard dual operational amplifier, pretty much like two of every other operational amplifier in the world except optimized for use as a comparator. It is intended to compare two voltages and have an output that is either "on" or "off" depending on which input voltage is greater.

The output pin is the collector of an NPN transistor whose emitter is connected to ground. If you want to imagine it's a perfect comparator, then the output will have a high impedance (output transistor off) to ground if the positive input voltage is greater than the negative input voltage or a low impedance to ground (output transistor on) if the positive input voltage is less than the negative input voltage.